# SQL Developer on virtual machine

Tags: oracle, virtual-machine

I am trying to learn Oracle. So I am using pre-install Oracle which runs on virtual machine, the information is in this [website](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/databaseappdev-vm-161299.html). I can access Sqlplus but I want to use SQL Developer. In this step:

[image]

They required admiration password, I try the password is **oracle** as in the website but it did not work.

[image]

Please give me some advises. 
Thanks.

Comment: "Didn't work" generally isn't helpful.

Comment: Check your names file to see if the hostname matches, as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've misspelled 'SYSDBA' as 'syssdba', with an extra 's'.

However, you can also enter the username as just `SYS`, and change the "Role" drop-down from 'default' to 'SYSDBA'.

You probably also need to change the connection settings to use *service name* `ORCL`, rather than *SID*.

Comment: Just put  `sys` in the username field.

Comment: @GlennFerrie - if you just put `SYS` in the username field and don't change the role you'll get ORA-28009 (or possibly ORA-01017 on older versions, from memory).

Comment: If you can't connect, go back to the basics. Can you connect as sys? Is something else wrong? Perhaps it was just the misspelling, but that's how I approach it.

Comment: @GlennFerrie - Huh? The question is about *trying* to connect as `sys`. If all you do is remove the misspelled `as syssdba` you'll just get the same error. (Assuming the OP is currently seeing ORA-28009, which is what you get with the typo; the rest of the settings look correct for the pre-built VM the OP is using but it is possible they're seeing something else since they didn't report the error they get.)

Comment: I hadn't noticed the misspelling at first

Comment: Hi, I tried like what you guys suggest: Username is sys, role sysdba but still not working. I tried the password to 'tiger' or 'oracle' but still getting the same error.

Comment: @ngoduyvu - you still haven't told us **what** error you get. But, you need to select the 'service name' radio button too, instead of 'SID'.

Comment: The error is : "Status: Failure -Test failed: Listener refused the connection with the following error: ORA-12505. TNS: listener does not currently..

Comment: @ngoduyvu - does not currently.... what, recognise the SID? Did you switch from SID to service name as in previous comment and answer edit?

Comment: Thanks you so much Alex, I change Service name orcl instead of SID orcl and It worked.